# Unable to use NRC lexicon in tidytext. Error in match.arg(lexicon) : 'arg' should be one of “afinn”, “bing”, “loughran”

Tags: r, text-mining, tidytext

I am learning sentiment analysis in R using tidytext package. However, i am unable to set nrc as lexicon. Whenever i type get_sentiments ("nrc"), the above error is displayed. It says that lexicon coud only be "afinn", "bing" or "loughran". I tried updating the package (tidytext) and also installed 'syuzhet' package but still the problem exists. Please help!

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by adding sample code and data that can **reproduce the problem**.

Comment: There are only three lexicons as the error states: `"afinn", "bing" or "loughran".` which can be seen in the arguments although I do recall using `nrc` some time. Perhaps it was replaced. No mention of it in the docs: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/tidytext.pdf

Comment: It was removed. See [here](https://github.com/juliasilge/tidytext/search?q=nrc&unscoped_q=nrc). If you really need to use it, just use an older version of the package.

Comment: I simply loaded tidytext package and accessed the 'sentiments' dataset from the library. According to the book, https://www.tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html , the sentiments dataset should be a 27,314 x 4 tibble. However, when i load it, R shows it to be a 6,786 x 2 tibble.

Comment: I read the CRAN page on tidytext and it also says that lexicon could only be "affin", "bing" or "loughran". I am using tidytext version 0.2.1

Comment: The book is behind the latest in the package. NRC was removed for licensing reasons. Sentiments only has the `bing` lexicon.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Cool then,nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace;

```
nrc_joy <- get_sentiments("nrc") %>% 
  filter(sentiment == "joy")
```

with;

```
nrc_joy <- get_sentiments("afinn") %>% 
  filter(value == 2 |value == 3 | value == 4 | value == 5)
```